# How to display current month as text and pass the value?

Tags: visualforce, apex

I have tried the second option first without considering your valuable advice but now I have over complicated the idea. I have tried passing the values as a date picker and then split them but that did not help me. I tried the below code and I will explain you the challenge I face now.

// I created a Map to store the values as you specified for different languages.

```
public map<integer,string> monthmaps(){

      map<integer, string> monthMapStatic = new map<integer, string>();
        monthMapStatic.put(1, Label.PD_General_Month_Jan);
        monthMapStatic.put(2, Label.PD_General_Month_Feb);
        monthMapStatic.put(3, Label.PD_General_Month_Mar);
        monthMapStatic.put(4, Label.PD_General_Month_Apr);
        monthMapStatic.put(5, Label.PD_General_Month_May);
        monthMapStatic.put(6, Label.PD_General_Month_Jun);
        monthMapStatic.put(7, Label.PD_General_Month_Jul);
        monthMapStatic.put(8, Label.PD_General_Month_Aug);
        monthMapStatic.put(9, Label.PD_General_Month_Sep);
        monthMapStatic.put(10, Label.PD_General_Month_Oct);
        monthMapStatic.put(11, Label.PD_General_Month_Nov);
        monthMapStatic.put(12, Label.PD_General_Month_Dec);
       return monthMapStatic;
}
```

// Then I ran the below logic but it only runs for current Month.//

```
for(Integer i=1; i<date.today().month()+1; i++){
this.monthList.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), monthmaps().get(i)));
        }
```

// I am passing the value as a string to the UI

```
monthSelection = String.valueOf(date.today().month());
```

Question: I can't give a Year or I have by default Year passing through, I need past 2 years. Hence the two dropdown option was asked

VF Page:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!monthSelection}"
  multiselect="false" size="1"
   styleClass="form-control pull-left monthlyDropDown"
   style="height: 33px;">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!monthList}" />
     </apex:selectList>
```

So the question still lies, how can give the option from the Map to the user for selecting Month from previous year.

Here is how they have previously passed the value to string SQL we are trying to pass.

```
joinQueryMonth += 'AND ((mcc.processing_year__c=\''+ thisMonthDate.year() +'\' AND mcc.processing_month__c=' + thisMonthDate.month() + ') \n';
```

I hope I am clear this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SelectOption`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) function accepts `value` and `label` parameters. So you can have more human-friendly label for month but still pass it as a number to Apex.

Here's quite complex demo. See [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45953865/revisions) for previous versions & explanation of some of the tricks.

```xml
<apex:page controller="StackOverflow45934022">

<apex:form >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Single dropdown</legend>
        <apex:selectList value="{!monthAndYear}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!monthAndYearOptions}" />
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!submitSingle}" event="onchange" reRender="results" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Two dropdowns</legend>
        <apex:selectList value="{!year}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!yearOptions}" />
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:selectList value="{!month}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="January"/> <!-- You can use itemLabel="{!$Label.PD_General_Month_Jan}" -->
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="February"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="March"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="11" itemLabel="November"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="12" itemLabel="December"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submitMultiple}" reRender="results" />
    </fieldset>
</apex:form>

<hr/>

<apex:outputPanel id="results">
    Month (as integer) : {!m}<br/>
    Year : {!y}
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

```java
public with sharing class StackOverflow45934022{

    public Integer m {get;private set;}
    public Integer y {get; private set;}

    public StackOverflow45934022(){
        m = System.today().month();
        y = System.today().year();
    }

    // Single dropdown version start
    public String monthAndYear {get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getMonthAndYearOptions(){
        List<SelectOption> ret = new List<SelectOption>();
        Date thisMonth = System.today().toStartOfMonth(), januaryLastYear = Date.newInstance(System.today().year() -1, 1, 1);
        DateTime d = DateTime.newInstance(thisMonth, Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
        while(d >= januaryLastYear){
            ret.add(new SelectOption(d.format('MM-YYYY'), d.format('MMMM YYYY'))); // you will use your map with month names to build labels
            d = d.addMonths(-1);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void submitSingle(){
        if(String.isNotBlank(monthAndYear) && monthAndYear.contains('-')){
            List<String> temp = monthAndYear.split('-');
            m = Integer.valueOf(temp[0]);
            y = Integer.valueOf(temp[1]);
        }
    }
    // Single dropdown version end


    public String year {get;set;}
    public String month {get; set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getYearOptions(){
        Date today = System.today();
        String y0 = String.valueOf(today.year()), y1 = String.valueOf(today.year() -1);
        return new List<SelectOption>{
            new SelectOption(y0, y0),
            new SelectOption(y1, y1)
        };
    }

    public void submitMultiple(){
        m = Integer.valueOf(month);
        y = Integer.valueOf(year);
    }
}
```

Comment: tnks Now that if I want to have two fields, one for the months and other for the past two years, how would I break it down? I am asking this because, my SQL takes number 10 as October and the year is the current year as default, I would like to have two boxes where I have all months this year(2017) (in this case August as I write) and all 12 months when i SELECT 2016. It would be great if you can help me with it. The Idea you have gave us is fantastic, but the previous SQL formed does not allow that, the only option I am thinking of is manually selecting a year and pass the values.

Comment: Thanks mate I am now trying both the options and I am trying the one you have suggested initially. Please correct me if i am wrong I would give the value={!monthlyselect} and then in the control side I give monthlyselect.year() and Monthlyselect.month(). I am learning somuch from you. Thanks for guiding people like me.

Comment: you were absolutely right with the second option, rerendering doesent work inside a collapsable, i am wondering how I would pass the values with the first option, please help.

Comment: How about building options as `new SelectOption(d.format('MM-yyyy'), d.format('MMMM yyyy'));`, this should give you values similar to "09-2017" (and labels will still be as month names). Then once something is selected, you could cut this string using split function. `List<String> temp = monthAndYear.split('-'); String month = temp[0]; String year = temp[1];`. And then either it can stay as is or cast with `Integer.valueOf(month)` or something like that.

Comment: I tried the first option and I miserably failed, can you help me build it @eyescream?

Comment: Edit the question, post the code you've got so far?

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look at it.

Comment: Hi mate, I am still waiting for your valuable response, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have considered eyescream first answer and have come up with the following logic

```
DateTime d = System.now();
for(Integer i = 1; i < 13; ++i){
            String label = d.format('MMMM yyyy');
this.monthList.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), label));
            d = d.addMonths(-1);
        }
```

The logic I used to pass it to my SQL query

```
Integer month_Sel = date.today().month()-(Integer.valueOf(monthSelection)-1);
        Integer year_Sel = date.today().year();
        if(month_Sel <= 0){
            month_Sel = 12+month_Sel;
            year_Sel = year_Sel-1;
        }
Date thisMonthDate = date.newInstance(year_Sel, month_Sel, 1);
```

Output for this would be like below

```
September 2017
August 2017
.
.
October 2016
```

Now my Query would take the values of year_sel and month_sel and return the year and month selection.

Thanks eyescream for your logic.